# "PCIe bus error" for modifyng fstab

Tags: boot, fstab, pcie

I modified `/etc/fstab` to change permissions over a mounted disk in Ubuntu 16.04, and now I can't start Ubuntu. First, it shows some messages, and then it starts showing this error until I shut it down (I've tried to press Ctrl+C, Crtl+Alt+F2, Ctrl+Alt+all other Fs, and many other combinations, but it won't stop showing that error).

[image: [error]

I think this problem would be solved if only I could modify back fstab, but I can't find a way to do it. I have found a solution to login in text-only console mode by pressing "e" in GRUB and adding `pcie_aspm=off` at the end of the Linux line. This allows me to start Ubuntu in a non-graphic mode without showing the error, and login with my user and password, but when I try to modify fstab it says that the system is in an read-only mode and that I can't modify the file.

Do you have any idea of how can I login some way that allows me to modify that file?

If it helps [here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/em6Xk.png) of the modification I made to the fstab file. The only thing I added is what is underlined in red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to boot your system on a Live USB, mount your root-filesystem (/) on /mnt and revert your changes to /mnt/etc/fstab. Then reboot.

Never try to change ownership or access-rights on files in / ... not with mount-options nor by `chmod`or `chown` !!!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try that and comment back if the problem is solved that way :D

Comment: IT WORKED!! My Ubuntu is back to normal.